# how to set an anchor on a div without text inside of it

Tags: html, css

is it possible to set an anchor on a div in which is no text?
I have this div:

```
<div class="greentotal">
   <div id="green-bottomright"></div>
   <div id="green-mid"></div>
   <div id="green-topleft"></div>
</div>
```

Styling with css, it shows me this:
[image]

The green ribbon is created with CSS only.
How can i set an anchor on this ribbon?

Answer (score 1):

You already have 3 anchors: green-bottomright, green-mid and green-topleft.
Simply doing doing a href or changing your url to `http://example.com#green-mid`

If you would want to add a new anchor, simply create a new id with an anchor name on the wanted element.

If you somewhere in your page want to add a link to a anchor element on your page, simply do the following:

`<a href="#anchorName">Click me and go to anchor</a>`

If you click that link, you will be scrolled to the specific element.